# Which points correspond to the resting positions of the differential equation? What is the value of H in resting places?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

It's given differential equation

$\dot{x}=p$

$\dot{p}=-x^3+x$

$H(x,y)=\frac{x^4}{4}-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{p^2}{2}+\frac{1}{2}$

How do I sketch the graph of the potential energy? Which points correspond to the resting positions of the differential equation? What is the value of H in resting places?

Answer (score 1):

The equilibrium points are just calculated when $\dot{x} = 0$ and $\dot{p} = 0$. As for the potential energy, just write $H(x, p)=T(p) + V(x)$, and evaluate $V(x)$ at the stable points you found in the previous step

[image]

Comment: So that points are when x and p are  0, are 0,-1,1. What is T and V?

Comment: Can you please answer me on those questiones or give better detailed answer?

Comment: Points are $(p, q) = \{(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, -1) \}$ and $T(p) = p^2/2$

Comment: What should I write $V(q)=\frac{x^4}{4}-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{1}{2}$? But what is the meaning of that? How do I sketch potentiale enrgy is that $V(q)$? What is the value of H in resting places?

Comment: $H(x,p)$ turns out to be the total energy of your system and is equal to the kinetic energy $T(p) = p^2/2$ plus the potential energy $V(x) = x^4/4 - x^2/2 + 1/2$. To find the values of $H$ at the equilibrium points just replace the values I just gave you. Hope it helps!

Comment: What when I replace what I'm going to get??

Comment: I mean not numbers, but what's the meaning. That's value of H? Right? Can you helping with sketching potential energy, how to do it? Just type V(q) in wolfram? haha

Comment: You're right, at the equilibrium points $H(x, p) = V(x)$

Comment: Can you give me tip for sketching potential energy?? @caverac

Comment: Can you tell me how did you get this graph?

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/simple_plot.html